# What’s the difference between wilt and die?

Tags: vocabulary

It seems like wilt refers to plants and die refers to animals and human beings.Can anyone help me clarify the difference?

Comment: If you are willing to consider adjectives instead of verbs, it is the difference between *dying* and *dead*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A plant *wilts* when its stems and leaves become floppy from lack of water. If it is watered, it will probably revive. It is *dead* when it is shrivelled and brown. (Of course, some plants die back naturally and new leaves grow from the root the next year.)

A person can be metaphorically described as *wilting* if they are too tired or unhappy to hold their head up straight.

Comment: People who are defeated in argument, thwarted, or who become discouraged about something, etc, are sometimes said to _wilt visibly_.

Comment: Wilt is also used for humans when it's extremely hot, for example we might say *"It was so hot yesterday I was wilting in the heat!"*  This usage is entirely analogy with the idea being that the human resembles, or feels like, a floppy, dehydrated plant.